# Reading Certificates on iOS Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, certificate

I am trying to read certificates from various URLs in iOS. My code however is not working well - the array that should return the information I need always returns `null`.

What am I missing?

```
- (void)findCertificate:(NSString *)url
{
    NSInputStream*input = [[NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://store.writeitstudios.com"]]] retain];

    [input setDelegate:self];

    [input scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [input open];

    NSLog(@"Status: %i",[input streamStatus]);
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    NSLog(@"handle Event: %i",eventCode);

    if (eventCode == NSStreamStatusOpen)
    {
        NSArray *certificates = (NSArray*)CFReadStreamCopyProperty((CFReadStreamRef)aStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates); 

        NSLog(@"Certs: %@",CFReadStreamCopyProperty((CFReadStreamRef)aStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates));

        if ([certificates count] > 0) { 
            SecCertificateRef certificate = (SecCertificateRef)[certificates objectAtIndex:0]; 
            NSString *description = (NSString*)SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificate); 
            NSData *data = (NSData *)SecCertificateCopyData(certificate); 
            NSLog(@"Description: %@",description);
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, I am aware that I am leaking memory. This is just a snippet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me explain what you're doing here and why it's wrong:

1. You are loading the contents of the URL https://store.writeitstudios.com (i.e. the HTML) synchronously into an `NSData` (a data buffer). Note that you are **not** loading any certificates (well, technically `NSURL` will load them internally, but this code is most definitely not putting them into the `NSData`)
2. You are opening an input stream and sticking the data (a bit of HTML, no certificates!) into it.
3. You have implemented `NSStream`'s delegate method `stream:handleEvent:` and are attempting to read the kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates property. This property will be empty since the stream contains only a bit of HTML data, nothing else.
4. You are casting the empty property to an `NSArray`.
5. The loop is not executed because the array is `NULL`.

Using `NSStream`/`CFStream` is not necessary for the task at hand. And most definitely you don't have to go through `NSURLConnection` first and then through `NSStream`.

**To retrieve SSL server certificates, stick to a simple, asynchronous `NSURLConnection` and use its delegate methods to access the certificates:**

```
// Method to begin the asynchronous download

- (void)beginCertificateDownload:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [connection start];
}

// NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
{
    return [[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    // extract the certificates
    SecTrustRef trustRef = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
    CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trustRef);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trustRef, i);
        CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certRef); 
        NSLog(@"%@", certSummary);

        // do whatever you need with the certificates here
        // don't forget to copy them if you need to keep them
        // around beyond the scope of this method
    }

    // I'm assuming you're not interested in actually loading the contents of the URL, so cancel
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    // you'll also want to release the connection object at some point
}
```

Comment: This script works well for websites such as PayPal, but doesn't return results for https://store.writeitstudios.com. Does this only recognize certificates from the most common cert authorities?

Comment: It does work for me on this website. Are you sure you were using the https URL? Are the delegate methods being called at all?

Comment: The delegate methods are indeed called. It basically just calls didStartConnection and didFinishConnection. It works for most URLs, but not for that one for some reason.

Comment: It works now - this was an error from my side. Is it possible to obtain information about the certificate such as issue date? I've seen this in Security.framework for Mac OS X, but not for iOS (the header file doesn't exist)