# How to pass SSL secure certificate in Socket programming

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets

I was working in Socket Communication in iOS. below is the code i have done.

```
- (void)TcpClientInitialise
{
    NSLog(@"Tcp Client Initialise");
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;


  CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)_IPAddress.text,(int)_port.text.integerValue, &readStream, &writeStream);
   [consoleLog appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IPAddress - %@ and port %d \n", _IPAddress.text,(int)_port.text.integerValue]];
    _console.text = consoleLog;
   [InputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey: (__bridge NSString *)kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings];

    InputStream  = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    OutputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [InputStream setDelegate:self];
    [OutputStream setDelegate:self];

    [InputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [OutputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [InputStream open];
    [OutputStream open];
}
```

but i not able initiate the connection. the problem is the Host is Enable with the SSL certificate. My Server team has said i have connect to the host with the certificate. and they have given the certificate. which is "digicert.crt"

Please help me how to connect to the host with using the certificate.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049508/in-ios-how-to-connect-to-a-server-using-https-with-self-signed-certificate-on-t